# Add a Sum Function within Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to add a sum function to my sql statement. Currently I'm using Oracle 12G;
my select statement is as follows

```
select Distinct o.id as ID, o.orderno as "order", a.itemno as "Item Number",
od.total_qty_ord/a.pallet_ptsper as "Total Pallets" From Orders o, ord_detail od,
arinvt a 
where o.id = od.orders_id (+) and a.id (+) = od.arinvt_id and   o.orderno = '1323-PASO'
order by ID
```

Currently when I run this I get two different records if my sales order has two different line items. I want to be able to sum the "Total Pallets" section of my script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Must the selected o.id also entered in de group by clause? I think so.

```
select Distinct o.id as ID,
o.orderno as "order",
a.itemno as "Item Number",
sum(od.total_qty_ord/a.pallet_ptsper) as "Total Pallets"
From Orders o,
ord_detail od,
arinvt a
where o.id = od.orders_id (+)
and   a.id (+) = od.arinvt_id
and     o.orderno = '1323-PASO'
group by o.order, a.itemno, o.id  ---> include the o.id
order by ID
```